# publish_actions review for a windows phone app

Tags: facebook

Can someone help me out on this ?

I am new to using Facebook API.

I am building a native Windows phone game app and I want to let my users be able to share their high scores on timeline. So, I need to submit my Facebook app for review (to get publish_actions permission).

I have a few questions:

1. What's the best way to submit my Windows phone app to the Facebook review team ? I want to release my app with the ability to share scores - so I really want to get this permission before publishing my app to the store. Will the review team be able to side load my package and test if I send them an xap ?
2. Is it sufficient to send a partially completed app (that includes all the pages that I use for logging people in and sharing scores) ? I would like to avoid exposing what my game concept is.
3. In future if I build a Windows 8 version of the game, will I be required to submit the Facebook app for approval again ?

   Thank you so much in advance.